# Insert table content in several tables

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table

I have several tables, all with different Id’s but with identical entries on different html pages. Is it possible to share the  automatically in only one place and then call it (or echo) into the rest of the pages?

Something like:

```
<table id="table1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ida</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Thor</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Diana</td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Chris</td>
        </tr>
</table>

<table id="table2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
Insert tbody from table1
</table>
```

Comment: You can use clone option complete table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your first table one be,

First define a class in tbody in table 1 be tableData1

```
    <table id="table1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tableData1"> 
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>       
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ida</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Diana</td>  
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Chris</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Let you table 1 insert into another table 2 tbody 2

```
<table id="table2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody class="tableData2"></tbody>
</table>

    $(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.tableData1').clone().insertAfter('.tableData2');
    })
```

Comment: Hi Whoami, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but you code is not working for me. I tried to insert both tables as above in the same html page, but the second table is empty???

Comment: @J.Birch, are you created <tbody> class created or not?

Comment: I am doing a exact copy of you code above. Is this what you mean? Sorry, i am a novice in html coding.

Comment: did you include jquery cdn or not

Comment: I included "<script src="../jquery/jquery-1.12.2.js"></script>" in the<head>

Comment: Include this in your head section  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166417/discussion-between-whoami-and-j-birch).

Comment: Are you ready for one last question?
It seems to be working fine when I have the two table in the same html page, but when I have the <tbody class="tableData1"></tbody> on one page and <tbody class="tableData2"></tbody> in another the second page is empty???